# R: Understanding formulas

Tags: r, formula

I'm trying to get a better understanding of what R formulas mathematically mean.

For example:  `lm(y ~ x)` would fit a line to `y = Ax + B`

Would `lm(y ~ x + z)` be fitting to the plane `y = Ax + Bz + C`?
Would `lm(y ~ x + z + x:z)` be fitting to the plane `y = Ax + Bz + Cxz + D`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. (The last two ones are a plane and not a line.)

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct! Though it may be helpful to understand it a bit more abstractly. Your linear model (lm) only means that it's fitting parameters on a one-dimensional dependance (Ax not Ax^2 or Asin(x) or anything fancier than that).

But that does not mean it only fits 1 to 3 parameters. Imagine that foods represent dimensions: grains, fruits, vegetables, meats, and dairy make up our 5 "dimensions of food". These things are clearly relatable--and maybe not even independent--but still not totally describable in exactly the same ways. We can think of our model as the tool which gauges our coefficients--which in this food example we can imagine as "flavors", like sweet, spicy, sour, etc.

Our model then takes points in different dimensions (food groups) and attempts to relate them by their coefficient values (flavors) for a function. This model then allows us to describe other foods/flavors. This is really what most models "do": they "train" themselves on annotated data and build a relationship--linear models just treat flavors as directly proportional to the amount of food group.

I hope this explanation was helpful. If there's anything that's unclear, please let me know. Also, I would have made this as a comment but have not yet accumulated the required 50 pts. Sorry!